# Working around the lack of recursive protocol constraints in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

Swift 3 (Xcode 8 beta 6) currently has a limitation regarding "recursive protocol constraints". There is an open issue [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1445), and there's similar discussions going on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253236/swift-protocol-with-associated-type-type-may-not-reference-itself-as-a-require), [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15256) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869440/swift-xcode-7-beta-5-type-cannot-refer-to-itself-as-a-requirement). However, I still fail to see how one is supposed to work around this limitation. Is it possible?

Let's consider the simple example of a view referencing a view model and the other way around and lets not consider ref/value types as well as any retain cycles:

```
protocol ViewModelType {
    associatedtype V: ViewType
    var view: V { get }
}

struct ViewModel<V: ViewType>: ViewModelType {
    var view: V
}


protocol ViewType {
    associatedtype VM: ViewModelType
    var viewModel: VM { get }
}

struct View<VM: ViewModelType>: ViewType {
    var viewModel: VM
}
```

With the above code you will run into the `Type may not reference itself as a requirement` as discussed in the provided links.

Then (naive as I am), I thought I could work around this by doing:

```
protocol _ViewModelType {}
protocol ViewModelType: _ViewModelType {
    associatedtype V: _ViewType
    var view: V { get }
}

struct ViewModel<V: ViewType>: ViewModelType {
    var view: V
}


protocol _ViewType {}
protocol ViewType: _ViewType {
    associatedtype VM: _ViewModelType
    var viewModel: VM { get }
}

struct View<VM: ViewModelType>: ViewType {
    var viewModel: VM
}
```

This kills the error, but it basically just postpones the problem. Because now when we want to construct our concrete types, we end up in a never-ending loop of specializations:

```
let vm = ViewModel<View<ViewModel<View...>>>()
```

I believe this is a somewhat basic constraint I would like to put in my protocols but at the moment I fail to see how to do it. Is it possible to work around this until Swift gets updated? Or do I need to start introducing less strict protocols until this has been implemented in Swift?

**Update August 19, 2016**

After trying a lot to figure out the best way to to work around this issue, I believe I have found a solution that is acceptable and only requires minimal compromises:

```
protocol ViewModelType {
    associatedtype D: Any // Compromise to avoid the circular protocol constraints.
    var delegate: D? { get set }
}

protocol ViewType {
    associatedtype VM: ViewModelType
    var viewModel: VM { get }
}

protocol ViewDelegate {
    func foo()
}


struct ViewModel: ViewModelType {
    typealias D = ViewDelegate
    var delegate: D?

    func bar() {
        delegate?.foo() // Access to delegate methods
    }
}

struct View<VM: ViewModelType>: ViewType, ViewDelegate {
    var viewModel: VM

    func foo() {
        // Preferred, but not possible: viewModel.delegate = self
    }
}


var vm = ViewModel() // Type: ViewModel
let v = View(viewModel: vm) // Type: View<ViewModel>
vm.delegate = v
```

The main idea is that, a mediator object or a delegate object is introduced, to handle the communication between the view and the view model. The reference to this delegate is of type `Any` to break the circular protocol constraints. The only downside as I see it, is that the delegate needs to be set up "from the outside", from where the objects are created, and cannot be set in the `View` implementation. If one tries to do this, the error `Cannot assign value of type View<VM> to type _?` will appear.

However, with this approach we get the correct types without having to do a lot of specialization. Of course, one could add more protocols to have even more abstractions, but the same solution would apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By some reason / language shortcomings you have to use explicitly cast when assigning the delegate in `View.foo`: `viewModel.delegate = self as? VM.D`

But why do you use structs and not classes? I think you want classes, expecially you don't want all those View/ViewModel variables being copied around while modified - instead of being referenced - when you do something like

```
var vm = ViewModel() // Type: ViewModel
let v = View(viewModel: vm) // Type: View<ViewModel> 
vm.delegate = v
```

Especially

```
func foo() {
    viewModel.delegate = self
}
```

doesn't work unless you declare `View.foo` as `mutating`, and this would require almost everything (including the `ViewDelegate.foo` and `ViewModel.bar`) to be made `mutating` and `v = View(viewModel: vm)` cannot be a constant any more.

Although the solution below would also work with structs, I just changed everthing to classes:

```
protocol ViewModelType {
    associatedtype D: Any // Compromise to avoid the circular protocol constraints.
    var delegate: D? { get set }
}

protocol ViewType {
    associatedtype VM: ViewModelType
    var viewModel: VM { get }
}

protocol ViewDelegate {
    func foo()
}


class ViewModel: ViewModelType {
    typealias D = ViewDelegate
    var delegate: D?

    func bar() {
        delegate?.foo() // Access to delegate methods
    }
}

class View<VM: ViewModelType>: ViewType, ViewDelegate {
    var viewModel: VM

    // initializer needed, because we are no struct any more
    init(viewModel vm:VM) {
        self.viewModel = vm
    }

    func foo() {
        viewModel.delegate = self as? VM.D
    }
}


var vm = ViewModel() // Type: ViewModel
let v = View(viewModel: vm) // Type: View<ViewModel>
v.foo()     // View<ViewModel>
vm.delegate // View<ViewModel>
```

There's just one more thing: Why don't you assign the delegate in the initializer of your view class, like:

```
// initializer needed, because we are no struct any more
init(viewModel vm:VM) {
    self.viewModel = vm
    self.viewModel.delegate = self as? VM.D
}
```

Then you could skip the call to `v.foo()` in order to set the delegate.

Comment: This is better, thanks! I guess, this is as close as we can get with the current version of Swift.